# Razer Blade 14" Webcam Issues

Tags: 17.10, laptop, webcam

I have a Razer Blade running Ubuntu 17.10 on kernel 4.13.0-25-generic.
Its webcam is not listed as compatible [Razer Blade Ubuntu Compatibility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RazerBlade) and until today I hadn't gotten it to work in any apps like Hangouts, FB Messenger or Cheese.

Today I installed the [Zoom meeting client for Ubuntu 14.04+](https://zoom.us/download?os=linux) and connected to their [test meeting service](https://zoom.us/test). The webcam worked perfectly as far as I can tell. Any thoughts on why this might be? This is the only app that it works for so far.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
lshw 
    *-usb:2
            description: Video
            product: USB Camera
            vendor: 11121119-000KA336F
            physical id: 7
            bus info: usb@1:7
            version: 0.02
            serial: 200901010001
            capabilities: usb-2.01
            configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA 
     speed=480Mbit/s
```

and...

```
lsusb
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 093a:2532 Pixart Imaging, Inc.
```

Comment: Any progress on this? Facing the same problem in my Razer Blade